# What are stamps and letters called in the US?

Tags: terminology

I am writing an essay in which I need to refer to postal stamps and letters/"mail". Would an American audience understand what I mean when I say "stamps" and "letters"?
[image]

Comment: Last Saturday I dropped by the post office to mail several letters.  Postage stamps were affixed to the envelopes containing the letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether words are part of US English by consulting an [American dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/letter). As you can see, both these words have definitions that correspond to their British meanings.